# UI.Bootstrap moduler Uncaught error for version 0.9.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently trying to add a header to my html page by using 'data-ng-include' but I keep getting a "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module agentOnlineApp" error.  I have compared my code to several answers found on this site but none of them seem to work.  Below is my current code configuration for this problem.

profile.js

`var profileModule = angular.module('agentOnlineApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

profile.html

```
    `<script src="jscripts/js/ui-bootstrap-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="jscripts/profile.js"></script>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
       <div data-ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
    </div>`
```

header.html

```
<header >
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1">
        <img class="shelterShield" src="css/images/shelter-shield.jpg" height="33" width="45" align="bottom" style="margin-top:-12px;">
    </div>
    <h1 class="col-sm-11 col-lg-11" style="background-image:url('css/images/topBanner.gif');">Agent Online</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The `ui-bootstrap-0.9.0.min.js` file should be below the `angular.js` file. It's dependent on angular and bootstrap css ([see docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/))

Comment: Well it worked and now I can see my header but now it is giving me a 404 error because it could not load the tab and tabset templates.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from Ninsley who posted a comment that pointed out that I had my  tag calls in the wrong order.  I followed his answer by moving the  tag for the ui-bootstarp-0.0.0.min.js below the  tag for angular.js call and was able to get my program running.  Thanks Ninsly

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
<script src="jscripts/js/ui-bootstrap-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jscripts/profile.js"></script>
```